# $A \subseteq B \implies P\subseteq Q$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

> Suppose that $A \subseteq B$.
>
> If $A$ is isomorphic to $P$ (with isomorphism $\phi$) and $B$ isomorphic to $Q$ (with isomorphism $\psi$), does this imply that $P\subseteq Q$?

I am thinking yes, but I am not too sure.

Let $x \in P$, then $x = \phi(z)$ for some $z \in A$.
But $z \in B$ since $A\subseteq B$ and so $\psi(z) \in Q$.

But $\psi(z)|_A = \phi(z)=x$ and so, we must have that $\psi(z)=x$, i.e. $x \in Q$.

Is this argument valid?

Comment: No, not strictly as sets. As a simpler example, if $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic, they need not be equal as sets. Right?

Comment: No.  That argument doesn't work because you can't assume that $\psi|_A = \phi$.  In fact, you can't even assume that they have the same codomain.

Answer (score 2):

Your last step is invalid since you haven't assumed anywhere $\psi|_A = \phi$. Take for example $A = \Bbb Z, B = \Bbb R = Q, P = \{ \left( \begin{matrix} n & 0 \\ 0 & n \end{matrix} \right): n \in \Bbb Z \}$. Of course, $A \simeq P$ (as rings) but $P \not\subset Q$.

This answer may or may not be completely accurate because you haven't really defined which kind of objects/morphisms we're talking about, but this is the general idea.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Consider the following.  Let $$A = \lbrace x\in \mathbb{C}\mid x^{4} = 1\rbrace,\quad B = \lbrace x\in\mathbb{C}\mid x^{8} = 1\rbrace$$ be multiplicative groups.  Then clearly $A\subset B$.  Also, $A\cong \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, where here $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}:=\lbrace 0,1,2,3\rbrace$ with addition modulo $4$, and trivially $B\cong B.$  However, $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\not\subset B.$